# GStreamer-Sharp and .net core

Tags: .net-core, gstreamer-sharp

How can I use [GStreamer-sharp](https://github.com/GStreamer/gstreamer-sharp) with .net core? I can add the [GstSharp](https://www.nuget.org/packages/GstSharp/) to a .net core project, but it cannot find any of the namespaces.
I have tried to open the Nuget package and it looks like it only have a dll for .net framework 4.5.

Is there any way for it to work in .net core?

Answer (score 4):

It's a bit late but you may still find this useful.
You can't directly, but you can recompile the GstSharp source as a .Net standard project.
Like this

1. Download source. There seems to be [a bug](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gstreamer-sharp/issues/14) in the 1.14.4 (and probably in master too), so try with 1.14.0 first.
2. Create a .Net standard 2 project and add sources. You can reorder a project somewhat, for example remove Samples etc.
3. Add Nuget packages for [GioSharp](https://www.nuget.org/packages/GioSharp/) and [GLibSharp](https://www.nuget.org/packages/GLibSharp/). These are compatible with .Net standard 2.
4. In Padtemplate.cs replace `GLib.GType ret = (GLib.GType) val;` with `GLib.GType ret = (GLib.GType)val.Val;`. This is due to using a different GlibSharp than the original GstSharp.
5. Your project should look something like this:
   [image]
6. Compile and enjoy

You can also go here (https://github.com/ttustonic/GStreamerSharpSamples) and all this work is already in gstreamer-sharp dir.
Disclaimer: this is my repo.